# ¿Cómo crear una consulta preparada para mysqli desde un array con criterio WHERE?

Tags: php, mysqli

Respondiendo a una pregunta quise crear una consulta preparada de tipo `UPDATE` para mysqli generada desde un array.

He ideado este código, el cual funcionaría bien si el criterio del `WHERE` fuese el último elemento del array. Pero si no es el último la lógica se rompe.

La consulta preparada se crea correctamente:

```
UPDATE laTabla SET a=?,b=?,d=? WHERE id=?
```

Pero los parámetros no, el valor para el `id` debería colocarse de último en `$params`, pero se coloca siempre en la posición en que está, en este caso la tercera.

Este es el código:

```
$array = array('a' => 'valorA', "b" => "valorB", 'id'=>20, 'd'=>'valorD');
$params=array();
$idColumn='id';
$set="";
foreach($array as $k => $v) {

    if ($k!=$idColumn) {
        $params[] = !empty($v) ? $v : "";
        $set.="$k=?,";
    } else {
        $params[] = !empty($v) ? $v : "";        
    }
}
$sql="UPDATE laTabla SET ".substr_replace($set, "", -1)." WHERE $idColumn=?";

echo $sql;
var_dump($params);
```

`$params` queda así:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "valorA"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "valorB"
  [2]=>
  int(20)
  [3]=>
  string(6) "valorD"
}
```

Y debe quedar así:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "valorA"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "valorB"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "valorD"
  [2]=>
  int(20)
}
```

Aquí el índice no importa, simplemente yo quiero un array para pasar a `bind_param` donde cada valor esté en el orden que corresponde al marcador.

¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más simple que se me ocurre es sacar `id` del arreglo antes de empezar a armar el arreglo `$params`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$array = array('a' => 'valorA', "b" => "valorB", 'id'=>20, 'd'=>'valorD');
$params = array();
$idColumn = 'id';
$set = '';

// Buscamos y sacamos "id"
$id = $array[$idColumn];
unset($array[$idColumn]);

// Armamos los params
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $set .= "$k=?,";
    $params[] = !empty($v) ? $v : "";
}

// Agregmos a params
$params[] = $id;

$sql="UPDATE laTabla SET ".substr_replace($set, "", -1)." WHERE $idColumn=?";

var_dump($params);

echo $sql;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a67a45c4df0e5506ab75b7ae474f064978e17bf)</kbd>